# Using patchValue for select in angular isn't work

Tags: angular

I'm patching values to field in reactive form using the below code :

```
editPat(patient: Patient) {
    this.regForm.patchValue({
        _id: patient._id,
        firstName: patient.firstName,
        lastName: patient.lastName,
        disease: patient.disease,
        department: patient.department,
        doctor: patient.doctor
    });
}
```

In this function `department` and `doctor` formcontrols are containing select field and value does not appear in select . The value i'm assigning to formcontrol here that is value of option..

**problem** how can i assign value to select through `patchValue` .Please help me

---

### HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="department">Department</label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="department">
        <option *ngFor="let department of departments"
                value="{{ department._id }}">{{ department.Name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Actually i'm using this code and after saving data in db (i.e id) when i tried to patch value (for update option) other fields works but for select its does not work..

Comment: hi Farhat Mustafa first you do not need to patch one by one property, you can simple  patch your patient object into form by using this line
Object.assign(this.regForm, patient);

please share screen or code for your select tag html

Comment: please checkout y updated question @kushalshah and Object.assign isn't builtin function but patchValue in angular 8

Comment: Farhat Mustafa bind value in option like this 
[value]="department._id" let me know it's useful or not?

Comment: Farhat Mustafa  have you tried with Object.assign() function ? I am just asking

Comment: yes i tried but it does not work and [value] isn't useful

Comment: ok Farhat Mustafa can you please share screenshot of your departments array which you are showing as options and also please share value of 
patient.department ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either try the another way to patch the value , 
**UPDATED CODE**
**HTML file**

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="department">Department</label>
    <select (change)="patchValue($event.target.value)" class="form-control" formControlName="department">
        <option *ngFor="let department of departments"
                value="{{ department._id }}">{{ department.Name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**.ts file**

```
patchValue(value){
    this.regForm.patchValue({
        department : value
    });
    this.regForm.get('department').updateValueAndValidity();
    console.log(this.regForm.value);
}
```

Checkout my updated code .

Comment: Bro you didn't get my point ,once data saved in db select field value was department_id. when update option i want to patch values to fields as saved in db that's issue